# How can this controller code be made simpler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a number of admin pages where the user is presented with a grid of items.  The grids has a search panel above them where the user can filter by a number of fields.

When the user clicks search i do a post which then redirects to the Index page.  I am sure the code below can be done in a better way (in some scenarios i have up to 20 filter fields).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Filter(MySearchModel model)
    {
        var searchParams = new
        {
            fielda = model.FieldA,
            fieldb = model.FieldB,
            fieldc = model.FieldC
        };

        return RedirectToAction("Index", searchParams);
    }

public ActionResult Index(MySearchModel model)
{
 //do filtering, return view etc in here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than performing a post with a redirect, just change your original form to use a `GET` method and target the "Index" action directly.

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Index", null, FormMethod.Get))
{
    ...
}
```

That way you can eliminate an HTTP round-trip and get rid of the "Filter" action completely.